# Python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and I'm trying to build a program that searches for specified text under a chosen column from an excel file using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def filterFunction():
  
#Filters by user-selected column & text
fileList = os.listdir()
print(fileList)
chooseFile = input("Please select a .xlsx file: ")
df = pd.read_excel(chooseFile, sheet_name = ['Treatment Settings'])
df.values()

#filter user input text search by column
columnSelect = input("Please give me which column you'd like to search under: ")
substringSelect = input("Please give me which text you'd like to search for: ")

#Search for given substring in user-selected column
convertSheet = df['Treatment Settings']
gatherSubstring = convertSheet.loc[[columnSelect].str.contains(substringSelect, case = False, na=False)]


#Print user input & search/filter results
print('\n------Filter results for column "'  + columnSelect + '" and substring "' + substringSelect + '"------\n')
print(gatherSubstring)
```

The issue occurs in my line using .loc, where I get this error:

> ```
> gatherSubstring = convertSheet.loc[[columnSelect].str.contains(substringSelect, case = False, na=False)]
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'
> ```

Any idea on how to fix this? I thought .loc could only be used with dataframes so I'm not sure about the usage of list/str and .loc.

Comment: The problem is `[columnSelect].str`. `str` is an attribute of a dataframe, not a list.

Comment: You can use `convertSheet[columnSelect].str`, why are you using `.loc`?

Comment: Can you make sure that the indentation of your code is correct?